# How to restore .vmdk files to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, restore

I have around 30 .vmdk files and one .vmx (I think some configs). My question is how to restore the files into MSSQL? I saw some answers like - restore them into .mdf file and then in management studio, but I couldn't do this. 
Can you help me, please?
Sorry for my bad English.
Thank you!

Comment: You can't, thats a virtual machine disk file. You need to mount it then you can locate the SQL files you need.  Ask the source of the files what VM software the files were created under.

Comment: I can't understand. How to mount them if they are 30 files?

Comment: You mount each one, one-by-one via (presumably) VMWare or  http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

Comment: It is not working man. I can't find how to do this.. I don't know how to mount 30 images and get one mdf file or smth?